SearchKit Reg Broken
It seems that there is some error with matches pattern
It is not filling the sql correctly. I'm trying to find all contacts who traveled in years ending in 0 or 5
^[0-9]*[05]$
Here is the api version
{
  "version": 4,
  "select": [
    "first_name",
    "last_name",
    "email_primary.email",
    "Extra_IAA_Contact_Info.Primary_Cast:label"
  ],
  "orderBy": [],
  "where": [
    [
      "Extra_IAA_Contact_Info.Primary_Cast:name",
      "REGEXP",
      "\"^[0-9]*[05]$"
    ]
  ],
  "groupBy": [],
  "join": [],
  "having": []
}

And here is the generated SQL
SELECT `a`.`id` AS `id`, `a`.`first_name` AS `first_name`, `a`.`last_name` AS `last_name`, `email_primary_1`.`email` AS `email_primary.email`, `Extra_IAA_Contact_Info_2`.`primary_cast_6` AS `Extra_IAA_Contact_Info.Primary_Cast:label`
FROM civicrm_contact a
LEFT JOIN `civicrm_email` `email_primary_1` ON `a`.`id` =  `email_primary_1`.`contact_id` AND `email_primary_1`.`is_primary` = 1
LEFT JOIN `civicrm_value_extra_iaa_con_1` `Extra_IAA_Contact_Info_2` ON `a`.`id` =  `Extra_IAA_Contact_Info_2`.`entity_id`
WHERE (`Extra_IAA_Contact_Info_2`.`primary_cast_6` REGEXP "")
  AND (`a`.`is_deleted` = "0")
ORDER BY `a`.`sort_name` ASC
LIMIT 50
OFFSET 0

I couldn't find any specific documentation on this, but I assume a standard mysql regexp would work. Notice in the sql the regexp is ""

Doing more research, it appears that the  REGEXP operator isn't being handled correctly by the API.
The field mapping is correct since using a = works.
SELECT `a`.`id` AS `id`, `a`.`first_name` AS `first_name`, `a`.`last_name` AS `last_name`, `email_primary_2`.`email` AS `email_primary.email`, `Extra_IAA_Contact_Info_1`.`primary_cast_6` AS `Extra_IAA_Contact_Info.Primary_Cast:label`
FROM civicrm_contact a
LEFT JOIN `civicrm_value_extra_iaa_con_1` `Extra_IAA_Contact_Info_1` ON `a`.`id` =  `Extra_IAA_Contact_Info_1`.`entity_id`
LEFT JOIN `civicrm_email` `email_primary_2` ON `a`.`id` =  `email_primary_2`.`contact_id` AND `email_primary_2`.`is_primary` = 1
WHERE (`Extra_IAA_Contact_Info_1`.`primary_cast_6` = "100")
  AND (`a`.`is_deleted` = "0")
ORDER BY `a`.`sort_name` ASC

Update
I'm reasonably sure the issue is with where clause. If I look at the output, with is one of, and manually enter all the lookups, it works, but in the sql it's mapping all id's not the actual name.
{
  "version": 4,
  "select": [
    "first_name",
    "last_name",
    "email_primary.email",
    "Extra_IAA_Contact_Info.Primary_Cast:label"
  ],
  "orderBy": [],
  "where": [
    [
      "Extra_IAA_Contact_Info.Primary_Cast:name",
      "IN",
      [
        "1965A",
        "1965B",
        "1965C",
        "1970A",
        "1970B",
        "1970C",
        "1970D",
        "1975A",
        "1975B",
        "1975C",
        "1975E",
        "1980A",
        "1980B",
        "1980C",
        "1980D",
        "1980E",
        "1985A",
        "1985B",
        "1985C",
        "1985D",
        "1985E",
        "1990A",
        "1990B",
        "1990C",
        "1990D",
        "1990E",
        "1995A",
        "1995B",
        "1995C",
        "1995D",
        "1995E",
        "2000C",
        "2000A",
        "2000B",
        "2000D",
        "2000E",
        "2005Fall",
        "2005Spring",
        "2010A",
        "2010B",
        "2015A",
        "2015B",
        "2020A"
      ]
    ]
  ],
  "groupBy": [],
  "join": [],
  "having": []
}


SELECT `a`.`id` AS `id`, `a`.`first_name` AS `first_name`, `a`.`last_name` AS `last_name`, `email_primary_2`.`email` AS `email_primary.email`, `Extra_IAA_Contact_Info_1`.`primary_cast_6` AS `Extra_IAA_Contact_Info.Primary_Cast:label`
FROM civicrm_contact a
LEFT JOIN `civicrm_value_extra_iaa_con_1` `Extra_IAA_Contact_Info_1` ON `a`.`id` =  `Extra_IAA_Contact_Info_1`.`entity_id`
LEFT JOIN `civicrm_email` `email_primary_2` ON `a`.`id` =  `email_primary_2`.`contact_id` AND `email_primary_2`.`is_primary` = 1
WHERE (`Extra_IAA_Contact_Info_1`.`primary_cast_6` IN ("1", "2", "3", "18", "19", "20", "21", "33", "34", "35", "36", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "106", "107", "108", "109", "110", "131", "132", "133", "134", "135", "158", "156", "157", "159", "160", "162", "163", "172", "173", "182", "183", "192"))
  AND (`a`.`is_deleted` = "0")
ORDER BY `a`.`sort_name` ASC
LIMIT 50
OFFSET 0

As you can see, the API searches on
Extra_IAA_Contact_Info.Primary_Cast:name
but the sql is converted to the id, WHERE
(`Extra_IAA_Contact_Info_1`.`primary_cast_6` IN ("1", "2",...
This is never going to work with regex as far as I can see. Maybe I'm missing something?

based on the fact searchKit added the :name suffix, it looks like your field has an option list. Are you trying to regex match the raw value of the field, or the name of the option.

Also you have an extra \" at the start of your regex - is that something you have in the definition or did searchkit add that itself?

I didn't add the slash, but Coleman is correct, searching on name. It makes no sense to search on id's.
I also used .*[05][A-Z]$
